# Unable to Save in @SpringBootTest when using Transactional

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-test

I'm trying to create a simple integration test where I'd like to find a specific data using @RestController

```java
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK)
@AutoConfigureWebTestClient
@Transactional
public class TestControllerITCase {

  @Autowired
  private TestRepository repository;
  
  @Test
  public void getConstants_Valid_Success()  {
    this.repository.save(test);

     this.webTestClient.get()
        .uri(b -> b.path("/api/test")
            .build())
        .header(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        .exchange()
        .expectStatus()
        .isOk()
        .expectBody();
  }
}
```

The log shows that the Transaction began. It also shows the query that I'm trying to use SELECT (as is done by my endpoint), however it does not show any sign of any insert when I try to run .save().
Here is the log:

```
2023-11-15 11:26:03 [main] INFO  o.s.t.c.transaction.TransactionContext   : Began transaction (1) for test context [DefaultTestContext@3a1e803 testClass = ConfigurationControllerITCase, testInstance = com.gdn.rebate.management.system.controller.ConfigurationControllerITCase@7279d0f8, testMethod = getConstants_Valid_Success@ConfigurationControllerITCase, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [ReactiveWebMergedContextConfiguration@bb6bf68 testClass = ConfigurationControllerITCase, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.gdn.rebate.management.system.Application}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[[ImportsContextCustomizer@58a5b377 key = [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.reactive.ReactiveOAuth2ClientAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.reactive.ReactiveOAuth2ResourceServerAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.reactive.ReactiveSecurityAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.reactive.ReactiveUserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.reactive.WebTestClientAutoConfiguration]], org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@119020fb, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@25e2ab5a, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@35390ee3, org.springframework.boot.test.web.reactive.server.WebTestClientContextCustomizer@13e547a9, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.metrics.MetricsExportContextCustomizerFactory$DisableMetricExportContextCustomizer@aafcffa, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@ec54a5c9, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@2e9fda69, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestArgs@1, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestWebEnvironment@13c9d689], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map['org.springframework.test.context.event.ApplicationEventsTestExecutionListener.recordApplicationEvents' -> false]]; transaction manager [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager@44a3b4d9]; rollback [true]
2023-11-15 11:27:27 [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] WARN  com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Thread starvation or clock leap detected (housekeeper delta=1m38s779ms994µs100ns).
Hibernate: select configurat0_.id as id1_4_, configurat0_.created_by as created_2_4_, configurat0_.created_date as created_3_4_, configurat0_.mark_for_delete as mark_for4_4_, configurat0_.store_id as store_id5_4_, configurat0_.updated_by as updated_6_4_, configurat0_.updated_date as updated_7_4_, configurat0_.optlock as optlock8_4_, configurat0_.category as category9_4_, configurat0_.description as descrip10_4_, configurat0_.key as key11_4_, configurat0_.type as type12_4_, configurat0_.value as value13_4_ from rms_configuration configurat0_ where configurat0_.category=? and configurat0_.mark_for_delete=false
2023-11-15 11:35:19 [main] INFO  o.s.t.c.transaction.TransactionContext   : Rolled back transaction for test: [DefaultTestContext@67c907b0 testClass = ConfigurationControllerITCase, testInstance = com.gdn.rebate.management.system.controller.ConfigurationControllerITCase@cd19d0a, testMethod = getConstants_Valid_Success@ConfigurationControllerITCase, testException = java.lang.AssertionError: value
```

Comment: Why should it? First the transactional unit is your test method, it will not commit in between method calls. Second an transactional test method is rolledback after the test method.

Comment: As what I understand, the @Transactional method is supposed to BEGIN TRANSACTION in the start of a given method and then decides to either ROLLBACK / COMMIT TRANSACTION based on the exception. So I don't see how it won't commit between method calls, is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Transaction starts before the `test` method and ends (commits) after the test method. But tests always (by default) rollback. There is no commit in between, as that would mean multiple transactions, you cannot rollback a commit.

Comment: Does my test classify as multiple transactions? If I call a method with 1 save() and 1 findAll() method, does it count as 2 transactions or 1?

Comment: 1 as the test method is the transactional unit, which will be rolledback by default at the end (as you see in your logs as well).